# How to make footer appear at the end of page but not be sticky

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, vuejs3

I have found some similar questions on this issue but unfortunately they didn't work for my case. I want something that appears at the bottom of the page of my 2 step onboarding screen but If I scroll up, it shouldn't be sticky and shouldn't appear up with the scroll. Can anyone suggest anything?

I tried achieving this by using bottom: 0 and position: absolute, but that made footer sticky even if I scroll up.

If I removed bottom: 0 and make position: relative, that fixes the sticky problem but make footer appear up in step 1 of the screen and appears fine in step 2.

My footer class in MainFooter.vue component - It's the main wrapper class:

```
.footer {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 24px;
  padding-right: 24px;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: var(--black);
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: var(--white);
}
```

My onboarding.vue component layout structure:

```
<template>
  <div class="d-flex mb-3 justify-content-between">
    <!—header—>
   </div>

  <div class="d-flex flex-column ">
    <div class="px-2 flex-fill" v-if="currentStep == 1”>
     <!--Step 1: Language Selection-->
        </div>

        <div class="px-2 flex-fill" v-if="currentStep == 2">
        <!--Step 2: Agent Selection-->
        </div>
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex mb-3 justify-content-end">
      <MainFooter />
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that you're using `position: absolute` on the footer but the nearest positioned ancestor element has *no* position, so the footer positions itself relative to the document body instead.

You may need to wrap everything in another div to accomplish this, but if you did you could apply `position: relative` to the parent div, giving the footer an element that's *not* the document body to position itself to.

Please try this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/elastic-golick-iitxch?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue) example.  The slider can be used to change the page height to show how the Footer always stays at the bottom.

The important elements to take notice of is the `container` div around the footer, and the parent `page` div (some extraneous code removed for clarity)

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="content">
    ...
  </div>
  ...
  <div class="container">
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Giving `position: absolute` to the container div and `position: relative` to the page div will always position container at the bottom of the page div, regardless of whatever else resides inside the div.

```css
.page {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 80vw;
  position: relative;
}
.container {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

If you actually comment out the `position: relative` in the sandbox you'll see how the container div positions itself to the document body instead and reacts to scrolling.